# Facebook sharing button: how to fix response code 401 for portal users

Tags: html, salesforce, visualforce, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have created a facebook share button in my visualforce article details page. The purpose of the button is to share the article link and in the post it should also show the article title and description. The button is working fine and posting the content as expected for public sites. I have used meta tags for title and description for the share button and it is picking the correct title and description from it while sharing but I am having problem with portal users. The meta title and description are not picking up by the button while sharing and link it should share is `https://example.com/portal/apex/homepage?id=kA154000000CcnlXYZ&l=en_US`.

I have used facebook sharing debugger and checked that the response code is coming as 401 (authorization required) but I am not getting how to fix this. Please guys, need your help on that.

The code used for facebook share button:

```
<!-- Script for facebook -->
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;" 
    href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={!fbLink}&amp;
    src=sdkpreparse"><img src="{!$Resource.facebook_icon}" alt="Facebook"/>
</a>
**** passing the fblink from controller class
```

Comment: Dis this work for internal users?

Comment: yes ..it should work for internal users only.